# how to keep chrome driver in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am making a program that downloads files over 5GB from a specific site through Python Selenium. However, when a function call is finished while downloading a file, the Chrome driver is automatically turned off. Then you can no longer receive the file. How can I successfully receive the file while maintaining the chromedriver even when the function ends?

```
def get_data(self,download_list,first_year,first_month,last_year,last_month):
    self.driver=super().get_chrome_drvier(download_path=self.download_path)
    self.driver.get(self.target_url)

  for ... in ...
    for... in ...
         download_file_code ....




if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_data(prameter1,....)
```

Comment: Do you know the name of file in advance ? Also do you know in which directory it will get downloaded  ?

Comment: It is stored in a specific local directory but i don't know file name in advance

Comment: we can clear the directory before executing the test case and look a new file in the same directory, if file present then close the browser, if not then do not close and wait till the file is present. Does this makes sense to you ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use options before calling webdriver

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="the location")
```

I wish this gonna help you